# JPA multiple persistence units for dev/qa/stage/production

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, persistence.xml

I've looked for answers for this but haven't been able to find any so asking these questions to this very apt community!

1. I have a standalone java application that gets deployed in many environments: dev, qa, stage, production.   As such each environment has its own datasource/db and there are property files that govern different properties depending upon which environment the application is running from.   As such, in my persistence.xml I've defined a persistence unit for dev.   In the same file, I'd like to define the persistence units for the other environments as well.   When doing so, Eclipse (Indigo - latest) complains as follows: **"Multiple persistence units defined - only the first persistence unit will be recognized".**   I'm *assuming* that what I've done is legal and this is an Eclipse issue.. can anyone confirm?   Also, is this what best practices would dictate given my current setup?
2. I was under the assumption that any entity bean marked with a @Entity annotation would automatically get picked up without having to explicitly define it in the persistence.xml file like so: `<class>com.mycompany.model.MyEntityBean</class>`.  If I omit the explicit inclusion of the entity class in the file, the entity bean - although annotated - throws an error:  **"Class "com.mycompany.model.MyEntityBean" is mapped, but is not included in any persistence unit"**   What I have I assumed wrong?
3. My final question is regarding db credentials: is it best practice to put my db credentials in the persistence.xml file in plain text?  Are there any safer alternatives to this?

Thank you community!

p.s - I'm using EclipseLink as the JPA vendor not that it should matter??

Here is an example of my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Development">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.mycompany.model.MyEntityBean</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:db2://xxxxxxx" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxxxxx" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="xxxxxxxx" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="QA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.mycompany.model.MyEntityBean</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:db2://xxxxxxx" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxxxxx" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="xxxxxxxx" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Can you add your persistence.xml content, it would help everyone better to understand.

Comment: Hi Nayan, I've added an snipped of my persistence.xml thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. "Multiple persistence units defined - only the first persistence
   unit will be recognized" is Eclipse (Dali) issue. More about subject
   you can find from [bug 231527](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=231527).
2. Because you have standalone Java SE application, entities should be listed in persistence.xml. In specification this is spelled out as follows:

> ```
>       To insure the portability of a Java SE application, it is necessary
>       to explicitly list the managed persistence classes that are included 
>       in the persistence unit using the class element of the persistence.xml 
>       file.
> ```

1. If you do not want to have passwords as plain text, some information about alternative can be found from [EclipseLink documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Configuring_a_Data_Source_Login_%28ELUG%29#Configuring_Password_Encryption).

Comment: Thanks for the info Mikko!  I would have up-voted but I don't qualify as yet :)

Comment: Thanks Mikko, I've accepted the answer.    It appears multiple persistence units are indeed being honored and it is the eclipse built-in JPA plugin that is complaining

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off the erroneous warning by doing the following. These instructions are for Eclipse Luna.

```
Project Properties => JPA => Errors/Warnings
```

Check `Enable project specific settings`

Expand `Project` group

Change `Multiple persistence units defined:` to `Ignore`.